# VB.net abstract class understanding

Tags: vb.net, abstract-class

If I have a class called A and a class called B, if B inherits A that means A is the super class and B is the subclass. I have been asked to describe why class A is not an abstract class but as i see it class A is an abstract class A, as it has been created for Class B to use in the future, is it something to do with Class B not being able to access the fields in Class A as although they are private by default?

Class A looks something like this

```vb
Public Class A
    StartDate As Date
    Men As Integer
    Place As String

    Public Sub New()
        StartDate = Today
        Men = 0
        Place = ""
    End Sub
End Class
```

Class B Looks like this

```vb
Public Class B inherits Class A
    Grade As ExamGrade

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New
        StartDate = Today
        Men = 0
        Place = ""
        Grade = 'Easy'
    End Sub

    Public Function setGrade(grade As String)
        ExamGrade = grade
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: the first line of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type) wikipedia may give you a hint as to one big difference

Comment: The first two lines in your post make it a monster... yikes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to be abstract, class A must have the `MustInherit` keyword.

Abstract  (`MustInherit`) means that this class serves as base class only and cannot be instantiated with `New`. It also allows you to declare abstract (`MustOverride`) members with no implementation, i.e. no method body. The inheriting classes then must override the abstract members and provide an implementation unless they are abstract themselves (where a third level of deriving classes would then provide an implementation).

Note that you are allowed to call an abstract member. At runtime the implementation of the actual implementing class will be called.

See: [MustInherit (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/mustinherit)

Members are private if not specified otherwise. Specify them to be `Protected` to allow descendant classes to see them or `Public` to allow "everybody" to see them.

See: [Access Levels in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/access-levels)

```
Public MustInherit ClassA
    Protected StartDate As Date
    Protected Men As Integer
    Protected Place As String

    Public Sub New()
        StartDate = Today
        Men = 0
        Place = ""
    End Sub

    Public MustOverride Sub Print()
End Class

Public ClassB
    Inherits ClassA

    Public Grade As String

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New() 'This initializes StartDate, Men and Place
        Grade = "Easy"
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetGrade(ByVal grade As String)
        Me.Grade = grade
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Print()
        Console.WriteLine($"Grade = {Grade}")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now, you can use it like this

```vb
Sub Test(ByVal a As ClassA)
    a.Print()
End Sub
```

You can call `Test` by passing it a `ClassB` object.

Comment: Thanks Olivier that makes sense, so if they are public or protected class B can inherit them from Class A, if they are private it cant and it the class A must contain MustInherit.

Comment: MustInherit is only required if you do not want to allow someone to create the class with `New`. If a class is abstract you can also specify methods to be `MustOverride` and thus force the deriving class to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

A is not abstract.  Abstract means you cannot instantiate the class.  It means you MUST inherit it.

Use the abstract keyword to make the class abstract.  You can also make methods abstract as well.

If you want B to see certain methods in A, but not to anyone else, use protected keyword.

Sorry, VB uses the MustInherit and MustOverride keywords.

Comment: Why **"must"** you inherit from an abstract class?

Comment: Is that an answer to my question?

Comment: Yup it is.  Unless you have a better explanation.

Comment: And where in that article does it say you **must** inherit from an abstract class?

Comment: Oh. um. I dunno.  I guess the MustInherit keyword sort of gives it away.

Comment: Are you saying that just declaring an abstract class, without inheriting from it, is illegal?

Comment: Right.  MyAbstractClass cl = new MyAbstractClass() is illegal.  MyAbstractClass cl = new MyDerivedClass() will work.

Comment: I'm not saying instantiating an abstract class. I'm saying declaring an abstract class. You don't have to inherit from it if you don't use it. Agreed, it's useless, but "you MUST inherit it" is wrong.

Comment: Dude.  You're kind of muddler.

Comment: I don't know what a muddler is.